# How to make an c# object from json

Tags: c#, .net, json

I get the following response from a webservice:

```
{
  "data":{
    "foo.hugo.info": {
      "path": "logon.cgi",
      "minVersion": 1,
      "maxVersion": 2
    },
    "foo.Fritz.Task": {
      "path": "Fritz/process.cgi",
      "minVersion": 1,
      "maxVersion": 1
    }
  },
  "success": true
}
```

How must the json-object look like to deserialize this?

Or is there another way to get the values of the properties?

Comment: Do you want to deserialize it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the information once you've got it into your program? Whilst you could deserialize it into an object, that might be work you can avoid, depending on your objective.

Comment: You already have a JSON object. Do you mean how to translate it into a C# object? If so make a class with the properties `path`, `minVersion`, `maxVersion` and use something like JSON.NET to deserialize.

Comment: @Tragedian - I want to get access to the properties. Something like data.foohugoinfo.path. But I have only this string and don't want to parse this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [`JSON.NET`](http://json.codeplex.com/) library it's pretty trivial:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int MinVersion { get; set; }
    public int MaxVersion { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
string json = 
@"{
  ""data"":{
    ""foo.hugo.info"": {
      ""path"": ""logon.cgi"",
      ""minVersion"": 1,
      ""maxVersion"": 2
    },
    ""foo.Fritz.Task"": {
      ""path"": ""Fritz/process.cgi"",
      ""minVersion"": 1,
      ""maxVersion"": 1
    }
  },
  ""success"": true
}";
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

In this example I have used a `Dictionary<string, Data>` object to model the 2 complex keys (`foo.hugo.info` and `foo.Fritz.Task`) because they contain names that cannot be used in a .NET member.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why this answer is wrong.

Comment: It does exactly what I need! Also it uses a dictionary and can handle more than two data-entries. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using VS2012 or above you can do the following:

```
Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes
```

---

With your example, this results in:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public FooHugoInfo foohugoinfo { get; set; }
    public FooFritzTask fooFritzTask { get; set; }
}

public class FooHugoInfo
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int minVersion { get; set; }
    public int maxVersion { get; set; }
}

public class FooFritzTask
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int minVersion { get; set; }
    public int maxVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any code example on what serializer you would use to deserialize the JSON shown in the OP to those classes? I am particularly interested in the `foohugoinfo` and `fooFritzTask` properties.

Comment: This may not answer OP's question fully, but I have to say... mind=blown. I had no idea what lurked under the edit menu until now.

Comment: This isn't flexible, if a third variant is added, you would need to create yet another class and add this to the `Data` class as a property.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this site: http://json2csharp.com/

Paste in the json string and it will generate classes for you. I usually use this in hand with JSON.NET to deserialize an instance of the Root Object.

Comment: Please look at the JSON more carefully and notice the `foo.hugo.info` and `foo.Fritz.Task` keys. Now look at what the site you suggested generated for the `Data` class - pretty useless.

Comment: Good point. I've not had issue using the site before. +1 for your better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
    [DataContract]
    public class DetailedData
    {
        [DataMember(Name="path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "minVersion")]
        public int MinVersion { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "maxVersion")]
        public int MaxVersion { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "foo.hugo.info")]
        public DetailedData Info { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "foo.Fritz.Task")]
        public DetailedData Task { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "success")]
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "...";
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        RootObject obj = (RootObject)js.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Data.Task.MaxVersion); 
    }
```

Edit: same class for `Info` and `Task`

Comment: You could have used the same class for `Info` and `Task`. Other than that, good and complete answer, +1.

Comment: This works well, but what I forgot to write is that data: is dynamic. It can be any count of different items, but everytime with the path, minVersion and maxVersion members. Only the names (foo.hugo.info / foo.fritz.task) can vary.